# Adjectives and adjectival nouns out of possessive pronouns

Tags: meaning, adjective, pronoun

My question concerns adjectives and adjectival nouns derived from possessive pronouns. With regards to the former, my grammar book gives two ways of forming these, e.g., "der meine" oder "der meinige". Is there a tangible semantical difference? With regards to adjectival nouns, is it even possible to form these in such a case? My grammar book simply states that such "possessive adjectives" may be written both in lower and upper cases with no reference of adjectival nouns. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean with *adjectival noun* here. There's no adjective. What you *might* mean is a substantive use of a pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

There are no *tangible differences* in meaning between "der meine" and "der meinige". It is highly probable (although i cannot prove that) that regionally the one or the other is prevalent. "Der meine" is most probably more widely used than "der meinige".

"Der mein**ig**e" stems from the postfix "-ig", which is used to turn other words into *Adjektive* (adjectives): "fahren - fahrig", "Wert - wertig", etc.. For instance you can take a *Nomen* (noun), "Mut" (valor) and turn it into an *Adjektiv*, "mutig" (valorous), which is the property of someone who has valor. Similar "der/die/das meinige" - the one who is (has the property of being) mine.

Answer (score 1):

No difference between *with* -ig and *without* -ig.

It is not an adjectival noun because it is not an adjective in the first place. (see Tofro's comment).

Used not nominalised, you can think of an ellipsis.

> Hol mir meine Gabel, ich hole die deine/deinige [Gabel].
> (old use)

Used nominalised, there are only 2 meanings of the created words:
Living being which belongs to [pronoun], and your responsibility (doing your part).

> a) Jesus versammelt die Seinen.  (Jesus gathers his people)  (old use)
> b) Er tat das Seine.  (He did his part/his responsibility)

Usage b) appears strictly with verbs of *doing*, mostly *tun*, I guess. Meaning a) can appear in any gender while b) is always neuter.

> a.1) Jesus versammelte den Seinen/Seinigen. (Jesus gathered [the person] which belongs to him )

Meaning a) works best in Plural. Die Seinen/Seinigen, Meinen/Meinigen, Deinen/Deinigen, Ihren/Ihrigen, Unsren/Unsrigen